# Missing sap.h. how to solve this issue?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

My dev environment:

os : window 7 64bit
IDE : Tizen 2.4
installed packages : 
2.3.1 Mobile (whole packages)
2.3.1 Wearable (whole packages)
Tizen SDK tools (whole packages)
Extra ( certificate extension, Tizen Wearable Extension for 2.3.1)

and I want to use *sap* (samsung accesory package). So I included `sap.h` in my app code, but an error occurred when the project is built.

```
"fatal error: 'sap.h' file not found"
```

how to solve my issue?

thanks.

Comment: Please be clear about what you want, also do take care not to commit too many grammatical mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, my question is "how to included SAP package" I already installed "Tizen wearable extension for tizen 2.3.1". But build system can not find SAP package. This case, how to fix it? Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing this same problem, even with all the Samsung SDK installed.

Go to Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Tizen Settings and check "Samsung-sap" option.

That's it! All solved!

Regards.-

[image: The project properties page]

Comment: what if there is no samsung-sap?

Answer (score 2):

Before going with Anibal's answer, I needed to install the wearable extensions. They are a bit hidden in the update manager.

First you need hit the advanced button in the top right and then "Extras" pop up in the below listing. From there you can install the "Wearable Extension for 2.3.1" which contains the headers.

[image: update manager for tizen]

Answer (score 2):

I had/have the same issue while trying to run Tizen 3.0 wearable App with SAP.

Although I have installed all required extensions, the option samsung-sap was not available in my Tizen Studio in ***Project —> Properties —> C/C++ Build —> Tizen*** Settings. In this case, I got  "*file not found*" for **sap.h** all the time.

Below are the steps I followed in order to fix this.

**Step 1**: move settings files

- Copy **samsung-sap-2.3.1-device.xml** and **samsung-sap-2.3.1-emulator.xml** from ..*/platforms/tizen-2.3.1/wearable/rootstraps/info*/ to *../platforms/tizen-3.0/wearable/rootstraps/info/*
- Edit both files replacing occurrences of 2.3.1 with 3.0.
- Rename both files replacing 2.3.1 with 3.0.

**Step 2**: move headers na libs

- move folders samsung_extension and sap_client from */usr/include* in 2.3.1 platform to the related folder in 3.0 platform.
- move libs libsap_client.so and libsap-client-stub-api.so from */usr/lib* in 2.3.1 platform to the related folder in 3.0 platform.
- Make the steps above for both emulator and device folders.

**P.S**: I used 2.3.1 platform as reference but I think this work with 2.3.2 as well.

**P.S 2**: There is no warranty there won’t be any errors after this while using SAP. At least, I managed to solve the “file not found” error of sap.h header.

I am running Tizen Studio in an OS X system.

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling the wearable extension sdk. Go to your tizen sdk folder..-->>>  (C:\tizenSDK\platforms\wearable-2.3.1\rootstraps\wearable-2.3.1-device.core\usr\lib)
check libsap_client.so, libsap-client-stub-api.so are present or not.
if not then reinstall. 
Otherwise, add the libraries in the lib folder of your project and right click on your project.. go to C/C++ Build>Sttings>Tool Settings>C++ Linker>Libraries. Add the name of your library there. For example, if your library name is libvconf.so , in the libraries section, add vconf, give the library workspace path too.

Answer (score 0):

Open Package Manager:

- Install Samsung Certificate Extension (Extension SDK)
- Install Samsung Wearable Extension (Extension SDK)